# Fail if target was not generated

Tags: scons

In a SCons build setup that uses quite some custom build actions, I had a lengthy action that was repeatedly retriggered because a target name was misspelled. Is it possible to configure SCons such that it the targets of a builder (or all builders) is really generated to prevent such cases?

For example, given

```
target = Command('some_target_file',
                 'some_input',
                 'echo foo > wrong_target_file'
                 )
```

with `> scons --debug=explain` will always result in

```
scons: building `some_target_file' because it doesn't exist
echo foo > wrong_target_file
```

without failure. While I would like to get an error in the spirit of

```
Error: target 'some_target_file' was not generated
```

---

I could emulate the desired behaviour using something like

```
dummy = Command('dummy', 'some_target_file', 'cat $SOURCE')                 
Default ([target, dummy])
```

resulting in

```
...
cat some_target_file
The system cannot find the file specified.
scons: *** [dummy] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Can you extend your question a little bit, by roughly sketching the steps that SCons should perform for each Command in order to detect an error like this? More specifically, how is SCons supposed to know that `wrong_target_file` is the (wrong) target name within the (somewhat arbitrary) shell command? I think you best bet would be to convert your Command builders to proper builders, following our [ToolsForFools Guide](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools). By not explicitly using the target name in the command string you'd be slightly more protected against this kind of error.

Comment: In the real case, I have a `Builder` that calls an external tool instead of this simple `Command`. You are right that using the `$target` variable could help reduce one level of potential errors, but still the external tool could fail to generate the requested file and still report a success.

Comment: And what exactly should happen in this case? If your target file gets used as source to another Builder, SCons fails. If the target is an "end product", it simply won't exist when you try to use it. Apart from not existing, the target file could also be empty...or filled with gibberish. How does SCons know the difference between a good and bad file? In your last sentence you're using "could fail"...does that it mean it really fails, or that you fear it might fail? Because from my point of view, if your external tool fails but reports a success it's not really up to SCons to "cover this up".

Comment: @dirkbaechle  The error that lead to this question, was indeed caused by custom tools and not SCons. But I can not think of a scenario where we would declare a target file, but then not care if it is not created, and thus I am wondering whether there is an elegant and generic way of preventing such cases.

Comment: Simply copying the created targets to a different location via the `Install()` method would create a dependency for catching this error. This is the first thing that comes to my mind, but you probably have a lot of those targets? Other users might have better ideas but, as far as I know, the core sources currently don't offer an option to "check that the target actually exists after the build step". It's expected that the result value of the Build Action somehow reflects this...and checking again and again can be time-consuming when the project size is 100k files, or even more. ;)

Comment: Add a post action which would fail for those targets that you care about.. (depending on the platform, could be "if [ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ]; then
    echo "File not found!"; exit -1;
fi"